# Update the variable values using echo and JQ

Tags: jq

I am trying to run the below command to json file.

```
#arch=x86_64

#ram=4

#echo '{"System Arch":{"Arch":"$arch","RAM":"$ram"}}' | jq '.' >> test.json
```

Output of the command:

```
{
  "System Arch": {
    "Arch": "$arch",
    "RAM": "$ram"
  }
```

I wanted the values of $arch and $ram to be updated.

Thanks,
Naran

Comment: Hi Emix, thanks you for your reply. It help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
jq -n --arg arch "$arch" --arg ram "$ram" '{"System Arch":{"Arch":$arch,"RAM":$ram}}'
```

or

```sh
arch="$arch" ram="$ram" jq -n '{"System Arch":{"Arch":env.arch,"RAM":env.ram}}'
```

If the vars are already exported, the following will suffice:

```sh
jq -n '{"System Arch":{"Arch":env.arch,"RAM":env.ram}}'
```

---

Now, it's possible that you wanted us to write you a template system. Well, you haven't provided enough details about the system you want for that, but I can provide you the basics:

```sh
jq '.. | strings | gsub("(?<whole>\\$(?<var>\\w+))"; env[.var] // .whole)'
```

(The vars need to be exported for the shell to pass them to `jq`.)

I say it's the basics because it's not a complete solution.

1. There's no way to produce the string `$arch` if the corresponding variable exists in the environment.
2. Both `$host` and `$arch` will be replaced in `"$host/$arch"`, but `$host` won't be replaced in `$host_$arch`. (It will try to replace `$host_`.)
3. It will happily interpolate `$HOME`, `$USER` and any other env vars passed to `jq`.

Comment: And it's easy to export the variables for this one command: `arch=$arch ram=$ram jq -n '...'`.

Comment: Or use `jq -n  '{"System Arch":{"Arch":$ARGS.positional[0],"RAM":$ARGS.positional[1]}}' --args "$arch" "$ram"`

Comment: @chepner, I added a section on exporting the vars. I don't think using positional args is appropriate here because it's practically guaranteed that the set of vars will change over time.

Comment: Either you update the filter, or you update the arguments passed to the command.

Comment: @chepner No idea what you're you're saying?

Comment: I'm saying I don't see why the fact that "the set of vars will change over time" is a reason to choose positional arguments over evironment variables. If you use `env` and the variables change, you have to change `env.arch` to `env.foo`, etc, or you change the positional argument `"$arch"` to something.

Comment: @chepner what's easier and less error prone, shuffling a bunch of numbers around in your templates, or just continue to use the name of the vars you need. It's a world of difference. I suppose you could only add new vars instead of removing some, at which point you end up with a bunch of magical numbers. Again, highly error-prone.